# (PHP) Parse command

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I want to get values of command tags (GET, FROM, IN, etc.) My command is:

```
// My command
$_cmd = 'GET a, b FROM p IN a and c="I am from Sarajevo" or d>1 ';

// My parser
if(preg_match_all('/(GET|FROM|IN)\s+([^\s]+)/si',$_cmd, $m))
    $cmd = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [GET] => a,
  [FROM] => p
  [IN] => a
  [from] => Sarajevo"
)
```

I am looking for this output:

```
Array
(
  [GET] => a, b
  [FROM] => p
  [IN] => a and c="I am from Sarajevo" or d>1
)
```

As you see, problem is with **whitespaces** and **repeated command tags** in strings (like `from`). So how can I parse this command?

Comment: What if you skip the `/i`-modifier - wouldn't you be able to make sure that you're only counting `FROM` and not `from`? Would there be a scenario where the `IN` would involve a string with a uppercased `from`?

Comment: I guess that relates to SQL... simply use your SQL, don't try to develop an interface for that.

Comment: @Dor - Please don't advice SQL parser. I need to parse this for my ORM project.

Comment: @dino beytar: "Object-relational mapping (ORM) systems (and the “frameworks” that use them) are another frequent performance nightmare.", From the book *High Performance MySQL, Second Edition*

Comment: @Dor - Yes, you right. But I think, this command line helps me to get standardisation my project. So i suppose, i will get less trouble with upgrades. I just want to try this way. Maybe I am completely on wrong way.

Comment: @dino beytar: I suggest finding a different solution to your problem, other than ORM or alike. You could have a standard & good performance with another solution.

Comment: @Dor - thank you for answering Dor. I want to try this way until I crash the wall :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot easily parse that with a single regex. (It's doable, but not simple.)

You should use a simple tokenizer, where a regex again becomes a useful tool:

```
  preg_match_all('/\w+|".*?"|\W/', $_cmd = 'GET a, b FROM p IN a and c="I am from Sarajevo" or d>1 ', $list);
```

This gives you a simple list, where you just have to find the clauses that you are interested in, then remerge the subsequent tokens (though I'm confused about your use case):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => GET
        [1] => a
        [2] => ,
        [3] => b
        [4] => FROM
        [5] => p
        [6] => IN
        [7] => a
        [8] => and
        [9] => c
        [10] => =
        [11] => "I am from Sarajevo"
        [12] => or
        [13] => d
        [14] => >
        [15] => 1
    )
```

Comment: I got empty spaces after each item. Can you check your code one more, please? Am i wrong?

Comment: You can use `(?!\s)\W` in place of `\W` to remove spaces. If you want to merge the resulting parts you should keep the spaces however. (That's why I disabled that option again.) -- Really depends on if you need it as tokenizer, or just to break up the string parts.

Comment: Could I do this without using regex?

Comment: Of course; but that's just more work. (String functions and lots of PHP code is typically slower than preg_match.)

Answer (score 3):

```
if( preg_match_all('/(GET|FROM|IN)(.(?!(GET|FROM|IN)))+\s*/si',$_cmd, $m))
```

this means - find any char after keyword which is not followed by GET, FROM or IN whith whitespace after it

Comment: But GET is followed by FROM?! I see the idea, but does it work?

Comment: GET ... FROM - there is intersection

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop a scripting language for this. Regexps aren't suitable for these purposes.

Comment: So what's your solution without using Regex?

Comment: @dino beytar: You could be using Regex but that's absolutely not the main part of the solution. You'll need to develop (or use an available FOSS) an interpreter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29

Comment: You meant that, should i develop or use an interpreter without using PHP, or I've been already trying to develop an interpreter?

Comment: @dino beytar: I think that you already tried to develop one using Regex and I told you that this is not the way to develop an interpreter. But I also think that you should avoid trying to develop or use an interpreter because that will be a performance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the case insensitive `i` after the delimiter `/`. And also make sure there is at least one whitespace after the keywords.

Comment: What if `'GET a, b FROM p IN a and c="I am FROM Sarajevo" or d>1 '` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$_cmd = 'GET a, b FROM p IN a and c="I am from Sarajevo" or d>1 ';
$tpar = preg_split('/\s+(GET|FROM|IN)\s+/i', ' '.$_cmd.' ', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
array_walk($tpar, 'trim');

print_r($tpar);

// gives:
array(
  [0] => GET
  [1] => a, b
  [2] => FROM
  [3] => p
  [4] => IN
  [5] => a and c="I am from Sarajevo" or d>1
)
// the rest is straight forward
```

Comment: Output are not the same with you mention above. I think somethings wrong with your code? Am i wrong?

Comment: yes, I missed the "form" inside the quotes, I am anwsering without PHP box.